# Install Google Chrome on SLES 11.2

Tags: sles, google-chrome, sles11

Is there an easy way to install Google Chrome on SuSE Enterprise 11.2?

The OpenSuse rpm from the Chrome web site does not work, it fails with some missing dependencies.

Any other easy way to install Chrome?

Comment: Have you been trying the 32bit or the x64 version?

Comment: The 64 bit rpm, the OS is also 64 bit (x86_64).

Comment: You could try the 32bit version of the Google rpm. Otherwise building Chromium from source might be a viable alternative. Several issues with SLES 11 and Chrome were reported.

Answer (score 2):

The 32bit rpm works fine on 64bit SLES 11.2. The 64bit rpm has missing dependencies.